# Is there a rift forming in Shingon since Eimei moved on?

Tags: shingon

When a school of Buddhism has a senior who passes away, is it common for the school to go into a type of dissarray, until a successor is chosen?
Some years ago I joined the Shingon school. It was awkward at the start, then upon the death of the (senior/master/sorry-correct-title-undefined), everything went sidewards. The body of the school seemed to splinter into minor sub schools, some casting doubt about other seniors. For a newbie this was disconcerting as the study of Shingon requires a 1 to 1 relationship, but my sensei stopped teaching, so I had to find another. Twas 3 years ago and I've still not found a replacement sensei. No new senior has been chosen.
Is this type of behaviour common in Buddhism?